# Origen de la expresión "sueño de la liebre"

Tags: etimología, modismos, historia, animales

El DLE, en la entrada "**sueño**", recoge la expresión:

[**el sueño de la liebre**](https://dle.rae.es/sue%C3%B1o#7lUypgn)

> 1. m. coloq. U. para referirse a quienes fingen o disimulan algo.

No consigo entender la relación entre la expresión y su significado.
¿Qué tiene qué ver "el sueño de la liebre" con "fingir o disimular"? ¿Cómo se ha forjado esa pintoresca expresión?

Comment: Encontré en Internet que este sería el origen de las expresión: Dicen los cazadores que las liebres duermen con un ojo abierto y otro cerrado y que no llegan a conciliar nunca el sueño por estar constantemente a la expectativa. Dormir como una liebre significaría "hacerse el dormido".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sueño de la liebre, El

Expresión figurada y familiar que se aplica a los que fingen o disimulan una cosa.
Se aplica especialmente a los que simulan estar dormidos, aludiendo a la vieja creencia de que las liebres no dormían o lo hacían con los ojos abiertos para estar siempre atentas a los peligros que acecharan, como expresa también el modismo DORMIR CON LOS OJOS ABIERTOS (COMO LAS LIEBRES).

[Fuente](http://www.librosmaravillosos.com/delhechoaldicho/index.html)

Dormir con los ojos abiertos, como las
liebres.

Dícese de aquellas personas que acostumbran tenerlos a medio cerrar cuando duermen, como sucede a las liebres por razón de lo sumamente cortos que tienen los párpados. Esta circunstancia hizo creer antiguamente a algunas personas que las liebres dormían con los ojos abiertos, de donde provino seguramente la frase : El sueño de la liebre, que se aplica a los que fingen o disimulan alguna cosa haciendo como que están dormidos.

[Fuente](https://archive.org/stream/diccionarioderef02sbaruoft/diccionarioderef02sbaruoft_djvu.txt)